# biblatex-chicago: authortitle option?

Tags: biblatex-chicago

I'm trying to use the authortitle option described in the [manual for biblatex-chicago](https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf). I've tried

```
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,authortitle=false]{biblatex-chicago}
```

but I get `Package keyval Error: authortitle undefined`. I've made sure I'm running the latest version (2.2). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code we see that the option `authortitle` is defined on the per-entry and per-type level, but not globally. `chicago-dates-common.cbx` has

```
\DeclareBiblatexOption{type,entry}[boolean]{authortitle}[true]{%
  \settoggle{cms@authortitle}{#1}}%
```

So you cannot say `authortitle=false,` at load-time, but you can say

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[dataset]{authortitle=false}
```

(As far as I know this is the only relevant setting you have to counter, because `biblatex-chicago` only sets `authortitle=true,` for `@dataset` entries, all other types are not affected.)

Comment: This didn't work for me, `! Package xkeyval Error: \`authortitle' undefined in families \`blx@opt@typ'.` Any ideas?

Comment: @jessexknight The example at https://gist.github.com/moewew/a3bb2524fcd1e01d12a22ec9ae010311 compiles fine for me (no errors) and the `authortitle` option appears to be working as advertised. I should note that I tested this with the current version of `biblatex-chicago` (2022/07/02, v2.3a). If you are using an older version, you might get errors.